# Older date in Spreadsheets Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get information of newly created files in a G drive folder. Everytime I run my program the output should refer only to new files in the folder. The D column will contain the creation dates. So I read the last value of the D column, let's call it DX; DX would have the creation date of the newest file (because I sorted them in the last line of the program). Then I compare DX to the creation dates of all the files in my folder. Only the files.creationDate > DX are the ones I need. I've managed to come up with:

```
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1gsXZWKSPxAsFiyuaMMNTkg6n_4p9HOeU');  
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
//get value of D2
  var control_cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D2');
//get last non blank value in the D column and assign it to variable lastTimeCreated
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D:D').getValues().flat().filter(String);
  var [lastTimeCreated] = values.slice(-1)
//If D2 is empty assign an old date to lastTimeCreated
  if (control_cell.isBlank()){
    lastTimeCreated = '1/10/2020 12:00:00'
  }
  
  var varFile;
  var varTime;
  var dataRows = [];
  let i = 0;

  while(contents.hasNext()){
    varFile = contents.next();
    varTime = varFile.getDateCreated().toLocaleString();

    if(new Date(varTime).getTime() >= new Date(lastTimeCreated).getTime() && varOwner.includes(actualSheetName)){
      dataRows[i] = [varTime];
      i++;
    }
    else{
      continue
    }
  }
  const sortedRows = dataRows.sort((a, b) => new Date(a[3]) - new Date(b[3]));
```

The problem is the last `if` with the `new Date(varTime).getTime() >= new Date(lastTimeCreated).getTime()` statement. I think `lastTimeCreated` can't be interpreted as a Date and as a result they can't be compared. I know `varTime` is not the problem because the last line of this program works perfectly. Maybe the problem is the format date of both dates (?). I've also tried with `Date.parse()` for both variables but it hasn't worked.

My spreadsheet looks like this:
[image: Sample of the spreadsheet mentioned in the question]

Any help is widely appreciated.

**Edit**
The date format is this: 1/10/2020 12:00:00

**Edit 2**
As suggested, provided more information and added some more code.

Comment: You have not supplied a complete [mcve] and so variables like contents are undefined

Comment: As mentioned by Cooper, please share a sample/copy of your spreadsheet so we are able to picture what you're working with and be able to easily replicate it. Also so we can provide you with a working solution or suggestions if any.

Comment: As suggested by @Cooper and @Dan-f I improved the code. Basically, I get files from a folder, then I read their creation date. And then compare these creation dates to a variable `lastTimeCreated`. If the creation date of a given file is more recent than `lastItemCreated`, all the information about this file will be stored into an array, which I'll sort and print later.

Comment: Just got back on this now please mention me in the comment as "@DanF" so I will receive notification. Can you share your full codes?

Answer (score 0):

#### Get the last n days of rows of the list

Column D is date

```
function getLastNDaysOfRows(n=2) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ash = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = ash.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let v = vs.slice();
  v.sort((a,b) => {
    let dta = new Date(a[3])
    let vA = new Date(dta.getFullYear(),dta.getMonth(),dta.getDate()).valueOf();
    let dtb = new Date(b[3]);
    let vB = new Date(dtb.getFullYear(),dtb.getMonth(),dtb.getDate()).valueOf();
    return vB-vA;
  });
  dtn = new Date(v[0][3]);
  dtvt = new Date(dtn.getFullYear(),dtn.getMonth(),dtn.getDate() - n).valueOf();
  let ds = vs.map(r => {
    let d = new Date(r[3])
    let dv = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate()).valueOf()
    if(dv >= dtvt) {
      return r;
    }
  })
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(ds));
}
```